# Azure Static Web App function API refusing connection from web app

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I have a Blazor WASM app deployed to an Azure Static Web app with a managed .NET 8 isolated Azure Function API. When calling the API directly from Postman using the auto-generated web app URL + the API route I receive the expected response and can see a log in Application Insights. However when I call the same endpoint from within the deployed WASM application I receive an `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` response and a request isn't recorded in Application Insights. I have confirmed that this is functioning as expected locally.

The successful postman request:
[image: Successful postman request]

The Log in application insights:
[image: Successful request in Azure Application Insights]

My `appsettings.json` file that is packaged with the Blazor WASM app:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiBase": "http://localhost:7071"
}
```

The `launchSettings.json` of the Azure Function App API:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Project.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7071",
      "launchBrowser": false
    }
  }
}
```

The Azure Function app is deployed to the Azure Static Web App and the `SendContactEmailFunction` function is registered in Azure:
[image: Deployed azure function app with list of functions]

The error I receive in the console from the deployed Blazor WASM app:
[image: Blazor WASM app console error]

How the `HttpClient` is registered:

```
var apiBase = builder.Configuration["ApiBase"]
              ?? throw new ArgumentException("API base address not found in config.");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBase) });
```

The code that is calling the API function:

```
var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/send-contact-email", sendEmailRequest);
```

The Azure function code:

```
public class SendContactEmailFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ISender sender)
{
    private readonly ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SendContactEmailFunction>();

    [Function(nameof(SendContactEmailFunction))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "send-contact-email")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(SendContactEmailFunction)} function received a request.");

        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync(cancellationToken);
        var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendContactEmailRequest>(requestBody);

        HttpResponseData response;

        try
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to deserialize response.");
            }

            var emailCommand = new SendContactEmailCommand(
                request.Name,
                request.FromEmail,
                request.Message,
                request.RecaptchaResponse);

            var sendEmailResult = await sender.Send(emailCommand, cancellationToken);

            if (sendEmailResult.IsFailure)
            {
                logger.LogError("Send email command failed. Error: {Error}", sendEmailResult.Error.Message);

                response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

                var error = new ErrorResponse
                {
                    Code = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    Message = sendEmailResult.Error.Message
                };

                await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(error, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                await response.WriteAsJsonAsync("", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e, "Exception occured. Error: '{Message}'", e.Message);

            response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(ErrorResponse.Generic, cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is possible can you share your repository here.

Comment: Unfortunately not @AsleshaKantamsetti, it's a private repo.

Comment: Is it possible to share SendContactEmailFunction

Comment: @AsleshaKantamsetti I've updated the question with the function code but as I said, it's being executed fine when called directly - just not from the Blazor app.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://i.imgur.com/EkGsj9V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working but I'm not quite sure what solved this in the end out of the two things I tried:

1. I deleted and recreated the Azure Static Web App.
2. I added a conditional check for hosting environment in the `Program.cs` file for the API base address. If in development - user the Function App URI from the `appsettings.json`. If not use the hosting environment base address:

   string apiBase;
   if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
   {
   apiBase = builder.Configuration["ApiBase"]
   ?? throw new ArgumentException("API base address not found in config.");
   }
   else
   {
   apiBase = builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
   }

   builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBase) });

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning how to program with C#/Blazor so take this as you will.  Why would the app be using the ApiBase of http://localhost:7071 when running as the Azure SWA? Shouldn't that be relative such that the static web app url is substituted?

Comment: Generally you'd be right in a more traditional deployment, but Azure Static Web App managed function APIs operate on the localhost of the SWA and are accessible via the /api prefix only on the generated SWA domain. CORs should be automatically configured to block any requests from outside that domain.